# Ajax call error from a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax post call from a javascript code is found below. I am getting an error message "fake error function" from Html page.

```
function interact(signal){
// loading signal
$('<div class="signal loading new"><figure class="avatar"><img 
src="/static/res/botim.png" /></figure><span></span>
</div>').appendTo($('.mCSB_container'));
// a POST ajax call

$.post('http://172.8.6.3:500/test', {
    msg: signal,
}).done(function(reply) {
    // signal Received

$('.signal.loading').remove();
    // Add signal to page
$('<div class="signal new"><figure class="avatar"><img src="/static/res/image.png" /></figure>' + reply['back'] + '</div>').appendTo($('.mCSB_container')).addClass('new');
setTime();
updateScrollbar();

    }).fail(function() {
            alert('fake error function');
            });
}
```

Comment: You correctly used a jQuery selector with `$('.signal.loading)` in one of the lines in your snippet, why are you passing in the HTML element as a string to the other selectors?

Comment: @dogui That HTML element needs to be displayed in index.html .

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: @madalin No, also its not hitting the API.

Comment: @sudeep123 Ah you're right, I normally use `.append()` so I didn't remember `.appendTo()`.

Comment: how do you call the function?

Comment: does your server accept post requests?

Comment: @madalin it accepts POST request and gives JSON object  {"text":"ServerMessage"} as response.

Comment: @madalinivascu now call is hitting api (changed browser proxy) but call  response is same.

Answer (score 0):

Does server

http://172.8.6.3:500/test

responses with origin headers?

If not, then add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com` where **example.com** is the server you opened on your page